# Unable to disable signups for Vaultwarden

Tags: docker, ubuntu, vault

Unable to disable Vaultwarden account creation.

Vaultwarden is running correctly, except disabling the registration.
I modified the docker-composer.yml like the following :

```
version: '3'

services:
  vaultwarden:
    image: vaultwarden/server:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8081:80"  # Use a different external port, like 8081
    environment:
      - DOMAIN=https://example.com
      - SIGNUPS_ALLOWED=false
    volumes:
      - ./vw-data:/data
```

Then I ran :

`docker-compose restart vaultwarden`

But the account creaton button still exist.

**Vaultwarden is an Unofficial Bitwarden compatible server written in Rust, formerly known as bitwarden_rs.**